# How to track Tweet Button clicks?

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter, google-analytics, same-origin-policy

I want to track tweet button clicks via Google Analytics, but tweet button is an iframe with content from another domain. Is there some tricks to add callbacks for tweet button click?

Comment: Are you looking to track clicks as a proxy for actual tweets? Because its actually easier to track that count than to track what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need a full statistics for clicks in Google Analytics and Tweet Button isn't an exception. Facebook Like button have "FB.Event.subscribe" function with "edge.create" event. Anything like this for Twitter?

Comment: Share! :) I am looking for a way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Or.. u can simply add event to your div and wait when this div well be clicked, like a:

```
<div class="clickMe">
   //twitter button there
</div>
<script>
$('clickMe').click(function(){
    //my awesome  code there
})
</script>
```

Sure, if you need only click, not callback.

Comment: Alright guys, please pay attention to the origin date of the question. It was asked more than a four years ago when Twitter API was not as good as nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a style="float:left;position: relative;display: inline-block" target="_blank" href="//twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechiessolution.com%2Fcss&amp;count=none&amp;source=tweetbutton&amp;text=testing%20Testing%20123%20Title&amp;original_referer=techiessolution.com">Tweet</a>

if (typeof twttr === "undefined") {
  $.getScript("//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js", function () {
    function handleTweetEvent(event) {
      if (event) {
        console.log(event['target']);
      }
    }
    twttr.events.bind("tweet", handleTweetEvent);
  });
}
```

Comment: There are related docs in https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
twttr.events.bind('click', function(e){
    // Send GA event
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: More than four years passed by the way :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

Tracking clicks on social buttons with Google Analytics

http://www.conversionworks.co.uk/blog/2013/05/16/tracking-clicks-on-social-buttons-with-google-analytics/

Answer (score -1):

One thought is to generate a UTM'd link for the Twitter button href, then add back into iFrame source page as the href source.  This will provide visibility into the click/session/user data on your Google Analytics tracking

To do this, first copy the original hyperlink and use as the source for [building the link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) using the Google link builder.  Once generated, come back into the iframe source page and add the new UTM'd link as the href source.