# Twitter and facebook share with callbacks?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have implemented facebook and twitter share to my website. The users are redirected to the following URLs when they click on the twitter or facebook share button.

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(text)

http://twitter.com/share?url='+location+'&text='+text

I want to store the username and tweet link if possible in my database when someone the content through twitter and I want to store facebook profile url and name when someone shares it through facebook. Is it possible to retrive that data when someone has successfully completed the share process?

Comment: For twitter look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947825/is-there-a-callback-for-twitters-tweet-button

Comment: Hello there ! is there any solution found for callback of twitter tweet ?

Answer (score 18):

The facebook javascript API allows you to share and gives you a callback

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```

To use this you need to have set up a facebook application and put the following code directly after the opening body tag

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: YOUR_API_KEY,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
</script>
```

If you ask for basic permissions, you could then get the users facebook id and use this to store which users had shared.

Comment: The FB JS code can be anywhere in your code, header, footer, in the body, it all works. The only thing that needs to be right after the body tag is the div.

Comment: You can put the div where ever you want and it works.

Comment: I need to have the application, and I cannot share the links which not allowed in application.

Comment: @Tom and what about twitter callback ?

Comment: Hi @TOm The above answer giving the error as Invalid App ID: The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID.

Answer (score 14):

For Twitter call with callback, that is how I did it in Javascript:

```
// Include the Twitter Library
window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
  var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
  js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

// On ready, register the callback...
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
        // your callback action here...
    });
});
```

The twitter link is like this:

```
      <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=URLTOBESHARED">Share on Twitter</a>
```

Reference: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events

Comment: A bunch of params for this link: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#tweet-intent

Comment: @tauan-scheidt-zimmermann callback is not working. There was no response  after tweet .. can you check it ?

Comment: will you please post some working example for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you open the FB share window, is up to the user to publish the content or not. There is no callback function and it's not possible to know if he has completed the proccess.

You may want to implement a FB connect and create your own form to publish into the user's wall once he has filled the fields (and also you have the option to save them in your DB).

I don't know if Twitter offers the feature that you are requesting, but I would go for the same solution as above.

Comment: There is an open feature request for a callback on tweetbuttons: http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=1835

Comment: This may be an outdated comment. Another answer on this page provided a working callback solution, whereas this answer claims there is none.

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook, there is an updated Share Dialog with callback (Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
 app_id=145634995501895
 &display=popup
 &href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
 &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer
```

You must provide an `app_id`, and the `redirect_uri` must be whitelisted in your App domains.