# how to share in twitter like sharing some text in facebook using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, python, twitter, facebook-javascript-sdk

When someone clicks a button in my website, I am able to share some content to facebook using this:

```
FB.ui(
{
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
},
function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
    alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
    alert('Post was not published.');
    }
}
);
```

Is there anything similar to that for tweeting some content in twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Head over here and read some more about twitter API reponses https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

Answer (score 0):

The [tweet Web Intent](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#tweet-intent) might be the most convenient analogue to your FB example.

This answer gives an example usage of a tweet web intent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19426405/1637295